# Question closed for lack of clarity

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed, unclear

I wrote [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77036314/13927534) a few days ago that got closed for lack of clarity. I quickly edited the question after that, and it's been sitting in the [reopen queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review) since.

I am mainly curious if you think the [original revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77036314/1) really did lack clarity, and if so, did [my edits](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77036314/3) improve the post? From my perspective, I don't really particularly feel like my edits added real value in helping answer the question, and were more of context explaining the "why" rather than the "how". I was trying to go for a minimalistic approach, sticking to the information that matters. Perhaps that's wrong and the context is important for the value of the question? (Or I should have done something else entirely?)

I think it may be argued that I could have worded the original revision better, and I'm biased in thinking it's clear because, well, it's my problem at the end of the day and nobody understands it better than me. This is why I've come here to get your perspectives on the matter.

Comment: I think initial revision was clear, and that later edit made it worse by bloating with unnecessary motivation description. It might help to solve your problem with proposed workaround or if you have XY problem, but for specific question asked IMO it is not needed.

Comment: @markalex Thank you for your input (and reopen vote). I agree, but I guess others might not (thus why it got closed). Hopefully someone can explain the other perspective as well so I can improve the question through a potential middle ground of improving the original revision without adding all the details around it

Comment: @markalex given that profiles of all close voters suggest solid familiarity with Maven I'd put a bit more faith into their judgement. To me, original revision reads somewhat unclear, as in - I'm not sure if I could reproduce the issue and propose solution because I don't understand what't the goal. In this sense later edits help quite a bit (FWIW I actively use maven for over 10 years, am quite comfortable with it and it is in fact my preferred build tool)

Comment: @gnat thank you for your input, could you please review [the latest revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77036314/4) and let me know if it clarifies the goal while avoiding potentially useless information?

Comment: looks pretty good but my perception may be skewed by the fact that I already saw your explanation in rev 3. I doubt that it is worth editing it back in, but to be on a safer side you may add something like, "Readers interested in more specific details of why I ask can find these in [revision 3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77036314/3) of this question"

Comment: @philipxy (felt like it makes more sense to answer [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77036314/building-specific-modules-in-multimodular-maven-project-dependencies-condition?noredirect=1#comment135872962_77036314) here) The linked question at the beginning is more of a background information than necessary to understand the question. I've seen multiple question start by linking a related question. That being said, I'm not opposed to removing it. (1/2)

Comment: As for the revision comment, I see your point. Once I settle on a version of the question that is clear and useful I'll have everything important self-contained in the question and delete the unnecessary comments. Until then, considering the apparent controversial nature of the issue being discussed, I think I'll hold off on making more edits/comments polluting the post and taking away from the actual problem its meant to address (2/2)

Comment: The original version of the question was perfectly fine. The vast majority of questions in the reopen queue are perfectly fine.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede that's quite the claim. If you really think so, I think it would be a good idea to start a meta discussion about it and improve the process. I don't have access to the queue so I wouldn't know, but just a thought

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What follows are personal conclusions drawn from this discussion to answer my own question and can hopefully serve as useful guidelines to follow:

- While debatable whether or not the question was originally unanswerable/should have been closed, the main issue resulting in the closure is that the goal was unclear. This is sensible, as answering a question without understanding the purpose limits the potential answerer to the box drawn by the asker and does not take advantage of other potential perspectives to reach the goal. This was improved in [revision 4](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77036314/4) as per [gnat](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/839601/gnat)'s feedback.
- In an attempt to clarify and have the question reopened, I added all the context surrounding my problem in [revision 3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77036314/3). As indicated by the previous point, this was not necessary as the crux of the issue was the lack of a clear purpose and that revision introduced a lot of useless information as indicated by [markalex](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/21363224/markalex)'s feedback.
- Revision 4 was quite stable, but just for the sake of following "best practices", I moved the argument against closing the question as a duplicate from the comments into the question as all important information should be self-contained. The initially added related quesiton was removed since it added no value to help understand/answer the question. This was done in [revision 5](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77036314/5) after [philipxy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3404097/philipxy)'s feedback.